# multithreading with ability to suspend/continue calculations

Tags: java, multithreading, continue, resume, suspend

I am writing Java program which allows me to get the geometric center of random-generated 2-dimensional points. I want the calculations to be done by custom number of threads. I want to suspend/continue calculations at any time. Unfortunately, my code doesn't work, It seems like `run()` is never executed. Here is what I got:

```
public void run() {
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

        try {
            System.out.println("running... " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

            PointInterface p = pg.getPoint(); // getting random point(x,y)
            pointCount++;
            int[] pos = p.getPositions(); // getting (x,y)
            System.out.println(pos[0] + ", " + pos[1] + " k");
            sumxy[0] += pos[0];
            sumxy[1] += pos[1];
            geometricCenter[0] = (double) sumxy[0] / pointCount;
            geometricCenter[1] = (double) sumxy[1] / pointCount;

            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("exception caught in run()");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Setting number of threads:

```
public void setNumberOfThreads(int threads) {

    threadsList.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
        threadsList.add(new Thread());
    }
}
```

Starting the calculations:

```
public void start() {

    try {
        for (Thread t : threadsList) {
            t.start();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("start() exception caught");

    }
}
```

Suspending calculations:

```
public void suspendCalculations() {

    try {
            Thread.sleep(1200);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("SuspendCalculations() exception caught");
    }
}
```

Resuming calculations:
I don't exactly know what I'm supposed to do here. Should I create new set of Threads like that?

```
public void continueCalculations() {

    int x = threadsList.size();
    threadsList.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        threadsList.add(new Thread());
        threadsList.get(i).start();
    }
}
```

How I run my program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ParallelCalculations pc = new ParallelCalculations(); // My main class object where run() and all the methods above are declared
    PointGenerator g = new PointGenerator(); // class that allows me to generate points
    PointInterface a = g.getPoint(); // getting random point

    pc.setNumberOfThreads(3);
    pc.setPointGenerator(g);
    pc.start();
    pc.suspendCalculations();
    System.out.println(pc.getGeometricCenter()[0] + ", " + pc.getGeometricCenter()[1]);

    pc.continueCalculations();
    pc.suspendCalculations();
    System.out.println(pc.getGeometricCenter()[0] + ", " + pc.getGeometricCenter()[1]);
}
```

**If needed:**
Point:

```
class Point {

    public static final int MAX_POSITION = 16;
    private int[] positions = new int[2];

    Point(int _x, int _y) {
        this.positions[0] = _x;
        this.positions[1] = _y;
    }

    public int[] getPositions() {
        return positions;
    }
}
```

Point Generator:

```
class PointGenerator {

    private int x = (int) (Math.random() * (Point.MAX_POSITION + 1));
    private int y = (int) (Math.random() * (Point.MAX_POSITION + 1));

    public PointInterface getPoint() { //  Can be called by many Threads at the same time.

        return new Point(x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can check for `run()` beeing executed by adding some `System.out.println(...)` at the beginning. And what is your Output?

Comment: It returns (0,0) as geometric center point's coordinates, always.

Answer (score 0):

Your `run()` should be executed and should do it's thing.

Though there is a far bigger cause for random behaviour in this code: All the threads write to `sumxy`, `geometricCenter` and `pointCount` at he same time without any syncronisation-locks, causing more or less random behaviour. You at least need to implement some kind of synchronisation to prevent simultanious writes.

Maybe start [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) (Java `synchonized` tutorial by Oracle) if you have no clue.

But simply adding synchronisation to everything will probably just make it slower than a single thread, you will need some kind of buffer for each thread to work independently and than collect the results when they are suspended.

And now general problems:

A) Your `suspendCalculations()` doesn't do anything (for 1200ms to be percise). To break the calcualtion you would need to interrupt all the worker-threads since they terminate upon interruption. Call `threadsList.get(i).Interrupt()` to do so.

B) If you want to to be able to change the number of threads while suspended, this is a way to go. If this is not necessarry, it would be more efficient to create a constant

```
 public static final Object LOCK = new Object();
```

make all the threads `LOCK.wait()` on that object, so resuming them is just a call to `LOCK.notifyAll()`.

C) Instead of using your own implementaion of Point you can use `java.awt.Point`.

D) Returning the coordinates of a point simply in an array is really bad for readability of your code, `java.awt.Point` has `getX()` and `getY()` functions.

Comment: "you will need some kind of buffer for each thread to work independently" Yes, I want the calculations to be done at the same time by each thread. I have no Idea how to properly implement that :/

Comment: At the core every Thread needs to have its own version of `sumxy`, `geometricCenter` and `pointcount` in order to run independently. But then none of these threads know the end result, so when you "suspend" your calculation, you will need to collect the results from each thread (make sure the thread is actually done beforehand) and and compute the grand total from that. (Something like `totalPointCount += threadsList.get(i).getPointCount()` for each of these fields and then do one final computation of the end-result)